# gs util get all folder size inside a path but not recursive

Tags: gsutil

How to get size of all the folder present within a specific folder in a gsc bucket.

this is how i am doing it using hadoop fs but this is too slow for directories where huge data us present

```
hadoop fs -du -s -h gs://path_to_folder
```

Comment: Have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du) I tried this  this `gsutil du -sh gs://path_to_folder/*`  and let me know if it works for you